# Why are date fields stored as integer in SQLite/MySQL databases?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, sqlite, types

I've noticed sometimes dates are stored as an integer instead of datetime in database. Why to choose Int while we have datetime data type?

Comment: As far as I know dates are stored in datetime or timestamp.

Comment: @JqueryLearner -  I've seen dates being stored as ints. For performance reasons they are stored integers and then use encoding / decoding to to store / retrieve them.

Comment: off the top of my head, iPhone message Sqlite db uses integer for all date fields and there are many open source projects with int date field

Comment: @WhoAmI You can not do calender operations if they are int

Comment: Are you asking for MySQL or SQLite? Java or iPhone?

Comment: @Pang for both MySQL and SQLite

Comment: @JqueryLearner - that is left to the underlying db / framework right?.  If it is designed to store date as int, then it can do the encoding/ decoding internally. Otherwise, yes, you are right, we can't do calendar operations .

Comment: They get stored as whatever you tell them to get stored as.

Comment: @DavidWallace don't you think that's obvious. The question was why to choose Int while you have date data type.

Comment: Well, if that's what you meant the question to say, you should have written that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**SQLite does not have a storage class set aside for storing dates and/or times. Instead, the built-in Date And Time Functions of SQLite are capable of storing dates and times as TEXT, REAL, or INTEGER values.**

For other databases you have wrong impression. Dates are usually stored as Timestamp or Datetime. Sometimes there are cases when people store UNIX Time defined as the number of seconds that have elapsed since 00:00:00  (UTC), 1970-01-01.

People tend to use UNIX time as it is usually easier to do time calculations/comparison, as you can apply usual mathematical operations to compare them. While with Timestamp/Datetime you might need to use time related functions.

What you mention regarding SQLite, it does not have a special datetime datatype.

Comment: for example if you see iPhone message backup Sqlite db it uses Integer for all date fields(date,date_read,date_delivered) and there are many other open source projects which stores date as an int

Comment: Yes, this is the case of using UNIX time. It's a developer's preference and you don't have to account for Timezone when using UNIX time (int). Also, SQLite does not have datatype for date/time.

Comment: If there are cases where dates are saved as integer, my impression is right ;)